# Problem with creating a tiff file in python

Tags: python, raster, tiff, gdal

I have the following segment of code:

```
    county = '003-alpine'
    candidate = 'trump'

    out_tiff = '/Users/deas/Documents/Python/precinct-master/data/tif/' + candidate + '/' + county + '.tif'

    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff').Create(out_tiff, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_width, 0, y_max, 0, -pixel_height))
    band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    no_data_value = 255
    band.SetNoDataValue(no_data_value)
    band.FlushCache()

    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options=["ATTRIBUTE=isHill"])
    target_ds_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    target_ds_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    target_ds.SetProjection(target_ds_srs.ExportToWkt())

    source_ds = None

    source_ds = gdal.OpenEx(shp, gdal.OF_VECTOR | gdal.OF_UPDATE)
    source_ds.ExecuteSQL("ALTER TABLE "+county+" DROP COLUMN isHill")

    source_ds = None
```

When I try to run this I get the following NoneType error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'.

Anybody see what might be going wrong here? I am very new to gdal so something very basic could be going wrong. I have all the folders created and in the proper positions.

Comment: Try storing the driver in an intermediate variable to see where your code breaks. Then check with the debugger whether the driver is None or `Create()` returns None. It might be that the tiff driver is named "GTiff" not "Gtiff".

Comment: Try to create an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's impossible to answer without knowing what your variables look like. An obvious guess would be that the output directory doesn't exist (GDAL won't create it for you). But things like `cols` as a float would probably also do it. Calling `gdal.UseExceptions()` after import will eagerly raise an exception when it occurs, instead of returning None. That might help clarify it a little: 
https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions

Comment: I believe I had the directories mixed up, thanks for your replies!